# PopupMenu that doesn't dismiss after clicking an item

Tags: android

I have a `PopupMenu` where the user can toggle which items are enabled or not.

However each time the user presses one, the menu gets dismissed.

Is there a way around this behaviour?

By request heres my code that Im currently using:

```
   final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
   final Menu menu = popup.getMenu();
   //Add menu items by menu.Add(..);
   popup.show();
```

Comment: It will be better If you add reference of your code that you have tried in your question.

Comment: Try "setCancelebale()" function for popup menu, and set it to "false" so it will not dismiss, untill you force it to dismiss.

Comment: @NetStarter I've added my code.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki There is no setCancelable() method for PopupMenus.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
    private void createPopup(View v) {
    popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popmenu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Random rn = new Random();
            int number = rn.nextInt(MAX);
            item.setCheckable(true);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "number :: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            popup.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```